# Почему в декораторе не могу распаковать список который состоит из словарей

Tags: python

Написал декоратор который получает список, внутри которого словари и должен вывести определенный результат, в зависимости от значения словарей.
Но при попытке распаковки списка, в декораторе список не распаковывается? В чем может быть проблема?

```
from typing import Callable


def only_admin(func: Callable) -> None:
    def inner(*args):
        for i in args:
            if i.get("is_admin") == True:
                create_permissions(*args)
    return inner


@only_admin
def create_permissions(users: list) -> None:
    for user in users:
        print(f'Creating permissions for {user["username"]}')

users = [
     {'username': 'admin', 'is_admin': True},
     {'username': 'moderator_a11', 'is_admin': True},
     {'username': 'custom_user1', 'is_admin': False},
     {'username': 'custom_user2', 'is_admin': False},
     {'username': 'admin_2nd', 'is_admin': True},
]

create_permissions(users)
```

Comment: В том, что args это не список словарей, а список аргументов

Comment: Не могу понять, а как тогда мне перевести его в список?

Comment: Ну например `users = args[0]`

Comment: Пробежаться циклом по i